# Длинный url (get-запрос) в file_get_contents

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, url

Здравствуйте. Работаю с vk API, отправляю сообщения обыкновенным методом `messages.send`, при помощи такого кода:

```
file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?message=".urlencode($message)."&v=5.60&peer_id=$pid&access_token=$token");`
```

Всё работает отлично, если я отправляю короткие сообщения (максимальная длина сообщения, которое мне удалось передать - ~850 знаков). Учитывая ещё то, что после `urlencode()` каждая русская буква = 3 символа, длина url получается довольно немаленькой. Но когда я отправляю сообщения большей длины, php возвращает `warning: file_get_contents ...`. Я попробовал отправить запрос через mozilla, но не получилось даже в ней (пишет что-то вроде не удалось установить соединение). Если попробовать отправить такой длинный текст с сайта вк - всё нормально, вк позволяет передавать сообщения такой длины.

Следовательно, проблема в длинном url. Как можно по-другому отправить запрос с таким длинным сообщением?

Comment: Что firefox вернул? Интересует Status Code.

Comment: CURL probovali ?

Comment: @АндрейАршинов, http ответ 400.

Comment: @L.Vadim, сейчас попробовал curl, но там ведь тоже в `CURLOPT_URL` я передаю длинный url. В ответ приходит пустая строка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправляйте запросы с помощью cURL методом POST примерно таким образом:

```
$parameters = [
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v'            => '5.60',
    'peer_id'      => $pid,
    'message'      => $message
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// в этой переменной JSON-объект, который вернет ВК
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

> сейчас попробовал curl, но там ведь тоже в CURLOPT_URL я передаю длинный url. В ответ приходит пустая строка

Это потому, что вы пихаете данные так же в GET-параметры, а надо в тело POST-запроса через параметр `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Просто я не знал, что vk API может работать еще и с POST-запросами. Теперь всё работает.